# how to fill the transparent part of an RGBA image with color, given the xy touch position?

Tags: python, image

i am trying to develop an android application in python that fills the area which is touched (exactly like the fill color tool in ms paint, which fills the closed area with color, or if not closed the color spreads everywhere).Given the xy position of touch, how can i fill the transparent area of a RGBA image using PIL or cv2, then save it?
given below is the pseudo code:

```
#rgb_value is the rgb value of the color with which to fill
#touchx, touchy are the xy positions of touch
#src is the source image, dst is the filename with which to save the output image
def fill_color(src, rgb_value, touchx, touchy, dst):
    #code goes here
    #then the image is saved
fill_color("freehand.png", [0,0,0], 5, 1000, "freehand(filled).png")
```

given below is freehand.png:(the patterned area is transparent)
[image]

Comment: `cv2` gives you numpy array with elements `(R, G, B, A)` and A is transparency - so you can check which element has `A == 0` to get transparent elements. As for filling you can use recursion - but it can be slow - you get first point and check its color. If it is tranasparent then you put color and you repeate the same code for pixel in neighborhood (so you have recursion) But maybe first you should check documentation for `PIL` and `cv2` if they don't have function to fill area.

Comment: wikipedia: [Flood-fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) - it describes how to use recursion to fill area.

Comment: @furas it helped a lot, huge thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv2` has `cv2.floodFill()`

It will get color in `start_point` and search the same color in neighborhood and replace with `color`

```
import cv2

img_before = cv2.imread('image.png')

img_after = img_before.copy()

start_point = (400, 300)
color = (128, 128, 128)
cv2.floodFill(img_after, None, start_point, color)

cv2.imshow('before', img_before)
cv2.imshow('after',  img_after)
cv2.waitKey(0)
    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but it works only with `RGB` but not `RBGA` so it would need more work.

---

`pillow` also has `ImageDraw.floodfill()` and it work with `RGBA`. If you work with `numpy.array` then it will need only to convert from `array` to Image and later back to `array`.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img_before = Image.open('image.png')

img_after = img_before.copy()

start_point = (400, 300)
color = (128, 128, 128, 255)
img_draw = ImageDraw.floodfill(img_after, start_point, color, thresh=50)

img_before.show()
img_after.show()

#img_after.save('image_after.png')
```

Comment: Much thanks, sorry for being late to upvote and accept your answer.